# How to make algorithm that guess function using input output data

Tags: algorithm, math

for example, input data is (number, time, ip) 2016222222, 20190722222222, 127.0.0.1 and output data is (11byte hex hash key ) a9485d3c334

I have many data but I don't know hash function.

So I want to know algorithm how to guess hash function using many input data and output data

Comment: try all known hash functions and match the results if no matching hash function fund you're out of luck ...

Comment: There are infinit many possible hash-functions with totally different design. So if it is not one of the common ones, you have next to no chance to guess it.

Comment: + they probably also use a salt, if this was hashed for encryption

Comment: @Spektre: It's not so hard really, because the set of all common hash function with a 44-bit output is as follows: {}.

Comment: The encoding of the data structure is also important. For example, the ip can be encoded as a string ("127.0.0.1"), or as an integer (2130706433). Both representations will give different hash results. Same thing for the time and number parameter. Make sure you try all reasonable encoding if you don't know which one has been used.

Comment: Perfect use case for machine learning!

Answer (score 1):

No sure way, but at least there are some approaches you could try.

1. Web search it. If you can control inputs even better. Hash of "123456" produces results for popular functions.
2. Find hash functions that have outputs of same length (11 byte seems quite odd, so there won't be many), check if it's any of them.
3. Try to analyse it. If it's a non-cryptographic hash, you might be able to deduce some pattern by trying many similar inputs and checking outputs.
4. Is there a code or binary of it that you can analyse?